# Winconn replacement on Ubuntu 15.04?

Tags: windows-7, rdp

I am currently trying to access Windows apps remotely using FreeRDP. I followed the steps found [Here](https://bmullan.wordpress.com/2012/09/17/howto-integrate-windows-apps-into-the-ubuntu-linux-desktop-using-windows-remoteapp/), and hit a stonewall. Apparently, Winconn is incompatible with 15.04, so I have no way of configuring RemoteApps easily in Ubuntu. So, I need to know if there is another way to get this done. Thanks to all that reply.

Comment: Wyh do you need "RemoteApps" if you're Remote Desktop-ing to a remote server?  We need more details on what exactly you're trying to achieve.

Comment: Sorry for not being clear. The goal is not to RDP into the desktop, rather I want to use the RemoteApp feature of Windows to run programs such as Microsoft Word in Ubuntu.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. This application has been unmaintained for a long time. Either look for another application or take over maintenance yourself.
2. This is probably just a dependency issue, I tried installing the package in a 15.04 VM with:

   ```
   wget https://launchpad.net/~realender/+archive/ubuntu/winconn/+files/winconn_0.2.14-1_all.deb
   sudo dpkg winconn_0.2.14-1_all.deb
   ```

   That resulted in the message that dependencies to `python-apport`, `libfreerdp1` and `freerdp-x11` couldn't be resolved. `libfreerdp1` isn't an installable package [it's contents](http://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty/amd64/libfreerdp1/filelist) seem to have been split up into individual packages some of them are: `libfreerdp-cache1.1 libfreerdp-codec1.1 libfreerdp-gdi1.1 libfreerdp-rail1.1 libfreerdp-utils1.1`. So install these with apt-get and find the missing ones through file listing of packages among [these](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=vivid&arch=any&searchon=names&keywords=libfreerdp) or install them all. Then run `sudo dpkg --force-all -i winconn_0.2.14-1_all.deb` and check if the application is running as it should.
3. Take over maintenance, build new packages from source for the release you want to use with updated dependencies.

---

> I followed the steps found Here, and hit a stonewall. Apparently, Winconn is incompatible with 15.04

Such statements are useless when you ask for help. They are rather counterproductive, other users feel tempted to answer with "*yep, it obviously is incompatible*" without looking further. Always provide detailed descriptions and error messages.

Comment: This will still have apt explode - if `libfreerdp1` doesn't exist then a metapackage needs to be created to install the other ones.  That's not hard to do, in fact I could make one in 20 minutes and have it readily available, but apt will blow up if a `libfreerdp1` package isn't present, I think.

Comment: @ThomasW. I didn't want to say that this is a proper workaround. Could you please be more specific on "This will still have apt explode"?

Comment: Even if the libraries are installed individually, apt checks the "Depends:" line for existing packages.  If no metapackage exists (like the current case), then it will say "Unresolved dependencies" because the package depended upon doesn't exist.  Therefore you remain in an "Uninstallable State".  It doesn't check the libraries individually - it checks for the existence of the packages on the Depends line.

Comment: Hi Livewire thank you for your post, I was able to at least get the tool up and running with your suggestions. I have another question relating to FreeRDP which I will post soon. Also, I will take you tips into consideration moving forward.

Comment: After running "sudo dpkg --force-all -i winconn_0.2.14-1_all.deb", the program works fine, however apt wants to remove it. I can't upgrade my system with "sudo apt upgrade -y" because it tells me to try "sudo apt -f upgrade". When I do, it says "The following packages will be REMOVED: winconn".

Answer (score 0):

it seems the author created a github.
Didn't try it yet but it should be here: https://github.com/RealEnder/winconn

you should just:

```
git clone https://github.com/RealEnder/winconn
```

hope this helps.