# winconn dependencies issue

Tags: apt, software-installation, 15.04, dependencies, ubuntu-gnome

I recently installed Ubuntu Gnome 15.04.  I have legacy apps I need to run in Windows, so I installed Windows 10 on another PC.

For integration, I want to use winncon and therefore also need freerdp.

winconn's dependencies are python-apport, libfreerdp1 and freerdp-x11. I couldn't use its ppa since it isn't updated. I installed all the dependencies myself but for libfreerdp1 which was split into pieces. I installed those pieces afterwards.

Now when I open the Ubuntu Software Center, it gives me an error:

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:  
winconn: Depends: python (>= 2.7.1-0ubuntu2) but 2.7.9-1 is installed  
         Depends: libfreerdp1 but it is not installed
```

winconn also fails with error -11.  I don't know if this is libfreerdp's fault or caused by some other issue.

I used these commands to install winncon on my system:

```
wget https://launchpad.net/~realender/+archive/ubuntu/winconn/+files/winconn_0.2.14-1_all.deb
sudo dpkg --force-all -i winconn_0.2.14-1_all.deb
```

I installed the missing dependencies: `libfreerdp-cache1.1 libfreerdp-codec1.1 libfreerdp-gdi1.1 libfreerdp-rail1.1 libfreerdp-utils1.1 python-apport freerdp-x11` using the Ubuntu Software Center.

Ps: My thanks to the community for editing this messy post!

Comment: I used .deb, by terminal you mean downloading the source and installing that?

Comment: I can't even find it in the software center, it's a package for 12.10 I believe.

Comment: yes for 12.04 and 12.10....it seems you followed [here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/630253/winconn-replacement-on-ubuntu-15-04)

Comment: Yes indeed, did I go wrong Ravan or is this really not possible to install on 15.04?

Comment: I installed all the depedencies via the software center and they were installed fine I think. Except libfreerdp1. Which I think could be the troublemaker.

Comment: Ok please edit and add the commands used to install dependencies!

Comment: `sudo apt-get install libfreedp1` use this command

Comment: Unable to locate it, in ubuntu 15.04, it's split into little pieces.

Comment: That installed, that's already good, thanks for taking the time btw!

Comment: Hast tou any more suggestions Ravan?

Comment: I asked you to edit question and add commands you used!

Comment: Oops, I'm sorry.  I'm very new to linux. They are added.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As you have already installed the necessary packages via

```
sudo apt-get install libfreerdp-cache1.1 libfreerdp-codec1.1 libfreerdp-gdi1.1 libfreerdp-rail1.1 libfreerdp-utils1.1 python-apport freerdp-x11
```

You can install the `winconn` package with a quick hack

```
cd; wget https://launchpad.net/~realender/+archive/ubuntu/winconn/+files/winconn_0.2.14-1_all.deb
mkdir deb$$
cp winconn_0.2.14-1_all.deb deb$$
cd deb$$
dpkg-deb -x winconn_0.2.14-1_all.deb deb
cd deb
dpkg-deb -e ../winconn_0.2.14-1_all.deb
perl -i -pe 's/libfreerdp1,//g' DEBIAN/control  
cd .. 
sudo dpkg-deb -b deb
sudo dpkg -i deb.deb
sudo apt-get install -f
sudo dpkg -i deb.deb
```

And here is a screenshot with winconn in Vivid

[image]

Comment: Oh my goodness, can't thank you enough.
That answer is ten times more detailed then I have ever gotten on any website ever. I'm blown away, thank you!

Comment: OMG! This works perfect to me! (Ubuntu 16.04)